# changing the padding of asp:textboxes using zurb foundation

Tags: forms, zurb-foundation

I know that foundation has built in form field css values to style forms.  These same values get applied to the asp:textbox, etc... .net controls because they render out as html client-side controls, but the padding between each of the asp:textboxes For some reason, is spaced differently:

[image: Example Image]

How can I correct this with the asp.net control?  I want the textboxes closer together and would like to stay with the .net controls.

Here's the code for each textbox (.net first and html second):

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 left">
      <label>Phone<span class="red">*</span>
        <asp:TextBox ID="contactPhone" runat="server" ToolTip="Phone" placeholder="Phone"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required"
            ControlToValidate="contactPhone" ValidationGroup="save" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <label>Input Label
        <input type="text" placeholder="large-12.columns" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply edited the label tag in the foundation css with a negative value (In my case -20) margin-bottom.  This worked perfectly for me.  Hope this helps someone else.